# How to process the output of a command line-by-line as a stream

Tags: powershell

Writing `SomeCommand | { ... }` pipes the entire output of `SomeCommand` to the code in the braces. Is there a way to "pipe" one line at a time and let the code in the braces process it line by line, without waiting for the whole output to be stored in memory?

**Update**

[Copied from comment]

`SomeCommand` is an executable (not a powershell cmdlet) that while running produces some output. It takes some time between the lines that it produces, and I do not want to wait until all the lines are produces to perform some operation on each line

Comment: What is SomeCommand? From your question, it sounds like it is a powershell command returning one multiline string (like calling an executable).

Comment: Going to depend on what `SomeCommand` is.

Comment: SomeCommand is an executable (not a powershell cmdlet) that while running produces some output. It takes some time between the lines that it produces, and I do not want to wait until all the lines are produces to perform some operation on each line.

Comment: It does not matter if you are using PS command, or just PowerShell cmdlet. If it outputs things, you can process them one by one without any extra work on your side. If that fails - I would blame command author. E.g. try: `ping -t localhost | % { $_ -replace 'time','after' }`. Ping is just executable, yet it works just fine in a pipeline.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for script block to be able to access pipeline, you need process block inside it:
Compare the two:

```
1, 2, 3 | & {
    process {
        $_
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

1, 2, 3 | & {
    $input
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Obviously, `Foreach-Object` (mentioned in previous answers) is usually better alternative than using script blocks in situations like this one, but since you asked for script block, script block is what you should also get...

Comment: I've seen your comment before... :) And no, it does not change my answer. Sole fact that it's exec not cmdlet does not mean that `$_` won't contain last line from your commands output (processed one at a time).

Answer (score 3):

In powershell, objects are passed item-by-item along the object pipeline.

> A related useful characteristic of pipelines is that because they operate on each item separately, you do not have to modify them based on whether you will have zero, one, or many items in the pipeline. Furthermore, each command in a pipeline (called a pipeline element) usually passes its output to the next command in the pipeline item-by-item. This usually reduces the resource demand of complex commands and allows you to begin getting the output immediately.

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347655.aspx)

There are some exceptions, though. Some commands (like `Sort-Object`), need all input objects to be able to send the result to the next step in the object pipeline.

In your example, You could use the ForEach-Object cmdlet (aliased as `%`) and use its special `$_` variable which represents the current item being processed:

```
Get-ChildItem $pshome | ForEach-Object -Process {if (!$_.PSIsContainer) {$_.Name; $_.Length / 1024; "" }}
```

**EDIT 2**
Since you are calling an executable, powershell will split stdout into lines as it receives them and send each string down the object pipeline. See the answer by @use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems odd that in order to something that is so commonly done using Bash (or other UNIX shells) I need to do some advanced tricks in powershell. I will keep looking for something simpler, and if I find I will post back as an answer. Otherwise, this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @AlexShtof I edited my answer because you would only ever need to use the OutputDataReceived event to process stdout entirely manually. For example, if stdout is not line separated, then PowerShell will wait to receive the entire string before sending it down the object pipeline. In that case, you could still use another command like Select-String with a regex and have PowerShell check stdout for matches as it comes in and send each one down the pipeline ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

Pipe the output from the (old-style) text stream executable through PowerShell's `foreach` cmdlet:

`ping.exe www.somesite.com | %{$_}`

Explanation: `%` is an alias for Foreach-Object. It cuts up a text stream at the newline characters and emits the lines one after another. Actually, most cmdlets that takes strings as pipe input will just work on the command line (it is actually PowerShell that cuts up the text stream, and not the cmdlets).